# Why "types may not be defined in parameter types"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

In C++20, we are allowed to have named initializers (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). The tl;dr; is that you can have named struct initializers, e.g.

```
struct Args {
  int a = 20;
  string b = "b";
  Foo* const foo; // must be defined
};

void Bar(Args x);

Bar({.b="woot", .foo=&f})
```

A more concise syntax (and one that seems to automatically provide for named parameters, if through one level of indirection) is:

```
void Bar(struct{int a=20; string b="b"; Foo* const foo;}) {/*...*/}
```

"[type definition in parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522183/type-definition-in-parameter-list)" states that it isn't allowed, but I'm wondering *why* it isn't allowed. Is there some funny c++ parsing/linking problem that would be broken with this type of declaration? Maybe it needs to be restricted to POD types or something?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a reason it can't be added, it just hasn't.  You can submit a paper asking for this.

Comment: @NathanOliver: "*You can submit a paper asking for this.*" Just be advised: it's been tried, and the ISO committee has not liked that general direction.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can see that.  Not really a need for anonymous structs.

Comment: How do you handle function identity now? If you have two overload declarations of that form, how do you decide whether they refer to the same function and whether the anonymous type is the same? If the token sequence is identical? Will the compiler need to put the whole `struct` definition in the mangled function symbol to correctly differentiate between overloaded declarations of this type?

Comment: @walnut the easiest way would be for the compiler to create a namespace just for that function that defines a hidden named struct type. Overloads whose constructors end up being ambiguous would give the same ambigous constructor error for bracketed initialization (That is, `call of overloaded 'Foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous`). That creates a usability issue for people creating these type of functions, and is different behavior than functions though.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sounds like an answer if you can cite a paper and its disposition?

Comment: @Barry: Actually, I realize that the [proposal I was thinking of](https://wg21.link/P0536) was somewhat different. There had been some discussion on the ML about a parameter version, but none of those ever got to a serious proposal form.

Comment: @IdeaHat: "*the easiest way would be for the compiler to create a namespace just for that function that defines a hidden named struct type.*" I think you're missing Walnut's point. How do you tell if `void foo(struct{int i;});` *declares* the same function as `void foo(struct{int i;});`?

Comment: @NicolBolas Seems similar - if there was discouragement (4-15) to have anonymous structs like that as return types, I'd be surprised if there was a different disposition to have anonymous types as parameter types? I mean, it's different (you'd never have to name the parameter type in any realistic context) but not like... _completely_ different.

Comment: This is either a mangling nightmare (if you need to mangle the class definition for declaration matching), an ODR nightmare (if you don't mangle the definition but allow it to remain unnamed), or completely pointless (if you require the struct to be named).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the comments into an answer (though a cited answer would be more useful):

It is hard for the compiler to determine if two different *declarations* of the function are the same. Technically each function declaration would declare its own anonymous type. Any tricks to get that to look like the "same" type would require a lot of type mangling, and would require the type to get named "under the hood" anyway.